# List applications running on a specific server - Websphere

Tags: websphere, jython

I am trying to list all the applications for a specific server Using Jython. My server name is causing an ADMA0184E exception

```
import java.lang.System as sys
applications = AdminApp.list("WebSphere:cell="+cname+",node="+nnmae+",server="+sname)
print "applications: " + applications
```

Output:

> com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMA0184E:
>   $sname is not a valid target

I have tried different variations of sname to no avail. jvm, jvm_01 jvm* I know that jvm is the name of a running server on the machine.

[WebSphere docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_listapp.html)

Comment: You should be able to use an unqualified server name in a command like this.   Interesting that the error msg mentions `$sname`.  Did you somehow mix and match TCL syntax in converting this from a Jacl -> Jython script?

Comment: it doesn't really mention `$sname` I was using that as short hand, to signify that any value I have for the `$sname` variable gets printed out in the error message, wheter it be jvm, jvm_01, etc ... sorry that might be a little confusing

Comment: OK.  Well, the message is saying your cell/node/server isn't a valid triplet.  So if you have the server correct then maybe the node is wrong or something.   Otherwise, the basic command seems fine.

Comment: @ScottKurz, looks like you were right. My triplet was wrong.